# AI: how can i detect if "i am under attack"?

Tags: unity, ai

I'm developing an AI. 
How can i detect if "I am under attack ?" so i can take a decision (flee and cover etc).

For under attack in mean something to check following conditions:

- if a bullet hit me or something near me

Thanks

Comment: Can you narrow the options specifying, what type of game is it(strategy game, FPS, moba, ...) and what kind of agents can attack it (AI, player, players over networks, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't precisely said what you call "under attack" I can see a few possibilities :

- If you have a health bar, you are under attack when it lowers. It is a very generic solution and it does not cover the cases when you hurt yourself by falling for instance, but it is very simple to implement. You just have to wait for HP variable to change as described in this Unity [question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1206632/trigger-event-on-variable-change.html).
- Check for collisions between your AI collider and specific weapons colliders such as bullets, swords, etc. I don't know anything about your project so those are suppositions. Look at what @Chris McFarland said.
- You can check for ennemies within a certain radius, it feels very intuitive and your AI won't wait for being hurt to react. You can use [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) for this purpose. More on this in this [question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/532746/finding-gameobjects-within-a-radius.html).

Answer (score 2):

As a rough idea:

When a bullet hits something, perform a [Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc.html) call (or if 2D, [Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc.html)) that checks for the layer that your creatures use, using the collision position as the center point with your desired radius.

For all nearby creature colliders found, you could have an `OnHeardSomethingNearby` method for each creature to call.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a state machine at all?  You could have a regular check to update the AI state when an event is called, and have the state machine use an attached listener for the event within a radius.  It's a bit more work, but it's extensible and very functional.  Plus it makes it easy to use a branching tree for reactions depending on the event that occurs (duck, find cover, return attack, etc.) as well as reacting appropriately if the attack stops and enough time has gone by (return to patrolling, search and wait, etc.).